# Suppress image loading errors in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, image

I am trying to show an image if a call to `http://localhost:someportnumber/icon` returns a zero size 200 response.

In most browsers, the following (cut down) works:

```
<img id="myImage" class="hidden-icon" src="http://localhost:someportnumber/icon">
jQuery.$('#myImage').load(function() {
    jQuery.$(this).show();
});
```

If the image doesn't load, the `img` element is never shown, and its all good.

However, Safari decides to report these failed image loads as page errors:
http://img.skitch.com/20090706-kna755s8fbb1pbd3mf9di9hdkg.jpg

As much as I have tried, I haven't found a good way of getting around these errors. Any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The older version of Safari is broken and the image.onload doesn't working properly.

So, to deal with it, I have used something where the images are loaded by script, then tested if they are there.

Simplified, something along the lines of:

```
// load the images
var img = new Image();
img.src = "http://whatever/image.jpg";
imageList.push(img);

: : :

// check
pollSafariImages();


// we have a poller to handle Safari as the onerror does not
// return 'this' to the image objects, so we don't know which
// one it was referring to
function pollSafariImages()
{
  var loadedCount = 0;

  var index;
  for (index=0; index<imageList.length; index++)
  {
    if (imageList[index].bLoaded == true)
    {
      loadedCount++;
    }
    else if (imageList[index].complete == true)
    {
      imageList[index].bLoaded = true;
    }
  }
  if (loadedCount < imageList.length)
  {
    setTimeout('pollImages()', 250);
  }
}
```

After a duration we check which images aren't loaded and replace them in our gui.

I hope the safari-hack is at least useful :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried inserting an if function to check that the image exists, and then only loading if it does?

You could also put something in the

```
<img src="blah" onerror="function to remove image if it doesn't load">
```

Comment: the onerror="" is what is causing safari to report the error. i can handle the error in that attribute, but afaict there is no way in js to stop safari from reporting it. (ie. its not actually a js error)

similarly with testing with an if function. the failed test causes safari to report an error